# How to log to Application Insights in F# Fable?

Tags: logging, f#, azure-application-insights, fable-f#

I am developing a [SAFE](https://safe-stack.github.io/) application in F#, and part of it is sending some logs to Application Insights in Azure. Server side logging is somewhat [easy](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Getting-Started-for-a-.NET-Core-console-application):

```
open Microsoft.ApplicationInsights
open Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility

let getTelemetryClient() =
    let key = <key>
    TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey <- key
    TelemetryClient()

let log (message : string) =
    let logger = (lazy getTelemetryClient()).Value
    logger.TrackTrace message
    logger.Flush()
```

Now I want to do something similar in the client side, in Fable. I have an AI key and I somehow need to send the data to Azure. The same code does not transpile to JS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved by means of [dynamic programming](http://tpetricek.github.io/Fable/docs/interacting.html#Dynamic-programming) in Fable.

1. Add AI JS dependency in `package.json`:

```js
{
    ...
    "devDependencies": {
        ...
        "applicationinsights-js": "^1.0.20"
    }
}
```

2. Reflect it in `webpack.config.js`:

```js
fsharpEntry: {
    "app": [
         ...
        "applicationinsights-js"
    ]
}
```

3. Set up logging (call this in the init phase of the app):

```fs
open Fable.Core.JsInterop
open Fable.Import.Browser

let setup() = 
    let key = <key>
    let config = createObj [ "instrumentationKey" ==> key ]
    window?appInsights?downloadAndSetup config
```

4. Log like this:

```fs
let log message = window?appInsights?trackTrace message
```

Maybe there are more adequate and/or type-safe ways, yet this works.

Comment: Cool. It might be worth looking into the AI typescript bindings for a more typesafe way of doing this. Also, maybe worth looking into a way to easily track navigation events between pages and correlating client and server events.